# Django looking for id with primary key field defined

Tags: django, database, models

I'm using Django version 1.10.1, and i have to use external database with read only permission. 
I have generated my models with inspectdb commands. Everything works well untill i changed one field to Foreign key because i must included relations that inspectdb doesn detect.
I have primary key's defined in both tables but when i define Foreign Key django looking for id field in referrence which is not exist in database.

That's error which i got:
`(1054, "Unknown column 'vicidial_callbacks.lead_id_id' in 'field list'")`

And here is my models:

```
class VicidialList(models.Model):
   _DATABASE = "dialer"
   lead_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   entry_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
   modify_date = models.DateTimeField()
   status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   user = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
   vendor_lead_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
   source_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   list_id = models.BigIntegerField()

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'vicidial_list'

class VicidialCallbacks(models.Model):
   _DATABASE = "dialer"
   callback_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   lead_id = models.ForeignKey(VicidialList, related_name='lead',to_field='lead_id')
   list_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   campaign_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'vicidial_callbacks'
```

So why Django looking for id column? Docs saying that Django wants to add its own id field until we have defined primary_key...

Comment: Could you provide the call which produces the error? I think I know what your issue is...

Comment: @Remi Sure 'queryset = VicidialCallbacks.objects.using('dialer').select_related()'

Comment: Facing the same issue, if you found some solution, kindly reply.